# I have a rate limit error with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i made small bot for price checking a crypto and it gives me rate limit after a few minutes
Its a small bot i do not know why it happens, i tried everything i could think of and ready the discord.py documentation........
Please look at my code and tell my whats wrong with it cause i have no idea..
edit #1
I changed the loop to 180 second i still got rate limited
edit #2:
Found the solution. the channel names can only be changed twice per 10 minutes i guess that was the problem

here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import re
from discord.utils import get

global loaded
global price
global sentmessage
global editname
sentmessage = False
loaded = False
price = "unkown"
Token = "asd"
starttime = time.time()
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = Bot(command_prefix="!", intents= intents)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
price = "unkown"
pingrole = "<@&asd>"


@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def refreshprice():
    global price
    global sentmessage
    global loaded
    global editname
    loaded = False
    if loaded == False:
        loaded = True
        driver.get("i removed the link cause its private and its not the issue")

      
    elif loaded == True:
        driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)
    buggyprice = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]",).text
    pricewithdollar = buggyprice.partition("\n")[0]
    price = int(re.sub(r"\D+", "", pricewithdollar))
    editname = client.get_channel(1078699389679325316)
    await client.get_channel(asd).edit(name="tfs " + str(price))

    if sentmessage == False:
        if price > 99999:
            sentmessage = True
            await editname.send(pingrole + " A fairspin kaszinó profitja 100k fölött van! GG a profithoz!")


        elif price < -99999:
            await editname.send(pingrole + " A fairspin kaszinó profitja -100k alatt van! Most rakd be a tfs-ed!")
            sentmessage = True

    elif sentmessage == True and price < 99999 and price > -99999:
        sentmessage = False


@client.tree.command(name="tfsprice", description="Check tfs token price")
async def first_command(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(" The casino profit is " + str(price) + "$")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()
    if not refreshprice.is_running():
        refreshprice.start()
        print("Ready!")

client.run(Token)
```

the error it gave was 2023-02-24 20:07:52 WARNING  discord.http We are being rate limited. PATCH https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1078699389679325316 responded with 429. Retrying in 242.03 seconds.

Comment: edit: here is the error:
2023-02-24 20:07:52 WARNING  discord.http We are being rate limited. PATCH https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1078699389679325316 responded with 429. Retrying in 242.03 seconds.

Comment: So wait until the end of the rate limiting period, then wait longer between each request - try 30 or 60 seconds, or check with the admins of the link you're using.

Comment: I advice you to remove the TOKEN from your post

Answer (score 1):

You are a new contributor, and so am I. Welcome!

Firstly, you should edit your post to remove/obfuscate the Token, as you shouldn't be disclosing credentials on here. Perhaps you should also remove other potentially private details such as the channel ID?

Secondly, if the API is returning a 429 status code as per your comment then you are being rate-limited. You can read more about the discord rate limits [here](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/blob/main/docs/topics/Rate_Limits.md). You might want to try reducing the frequency that the refreshprice function is called.